# installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.

Tags: 12.04, software-center, update-manager

I get the following error while updating ubuntu 12.04 LTS

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 430284 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libxml2-dev 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.1 (using .../libxml2-dev_2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.2_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libxml2-dev ...
Preparing to replace libxml2 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.1 (using .../libxml2_2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.2_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libxml2 ...
Preparing to replace gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad 0.10.22.3-2ubuntu2 (using .../gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad_0.10.22.3-2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad ...
Preparing to replace libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 0.10.22.3-2ubuntu2 (using .../libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0_0.10.22.3-2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 ...
Preparing to replace ubuntu-keyring 2011.11.21 (using .../ubuntu-keyring_2011.11.21.1_all.deb) ...


/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba4.postinst: 14: /var/lib/dpkg/info/samba4.postinst: /usr/share/samba/setoption.pl: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing samba4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
```

Answer (score 15):

Solution from [Robert Penz](http://robert.penz.name/461/solution-for-perl-warning-setting-locale-failed/), I'm posting it here.

Fix the warning by generating the locale(s) the warning is complaining about. To generate the locales run `sudo locale-gen` followed the locale.

For example this is the error I had:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "en_IE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_IE.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_IE.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_IE.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_IE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_IE.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_IE.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_IE.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "en_IE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

To fix I had to generate `en_IE`, `en_IE.UTF-8`, and `en_US.UTF-8`:

```
$ sudo locale-gen en_IE en_IE.UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
Generating locales...
de_AT.UTF-8... done
en_US.ISO-8859-1... done
en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

Done. Happy days.

To test everything is ok you can run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
Generating locales...
  en_IE.ISO-8859-1... up-to-date
  en_IE.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

Comment: "sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales" is all you need

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing the English **language pack**.
Install it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en
```

source: http://collingo.com/fixing-ubuntu-locale-errors/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the system is picking up `LANGUAGE` and `LC_ALL` as being defined, but blank (not set). You should be able to unset them and run your command.

`unset LANGUAGE && unset LC_ALL && yourcommand`